# Formatear campo fecha en Tabla HTML ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo una tabla HTML en la cual muestro los datos de una tabla de SQL Server, una de las columnas de tipo datetime y necesito que muestre la fecha sin la hora.
Aquí mi código:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
        <td>@Model[i].Codigo</td>
        <td>@Model[i].Nombre</td>
        <td>@Model[i].Fecha_solicitud</td>
        <td>@Model[i].Fecha_ejecucion</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo

```html
namespace Proyecto.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class ProdMuestreo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Codigo { get; set; }
  public string Nombre { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_solicitud { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_ejecucion { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Algunas veces el editor marca errores, pero cuando ejecutas la aplicacion todo funciona bien. Ya intentaste la vieja y confiable: cerrar el visual studio y abrirlo de nuevo, ¿Seguro que esos datos son un Datetime?

Comment: Agrega el modelo brother, entre más datos será mejor para dar con la solución, sino, te vas a pasar diciendo a todas las respuesta que te genera problemas o cosas por el estilo. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx ya lo agregue, gracias, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```html
<td>@(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model[i].Fecha_solicitud))</td>
<td>@(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model[i].Fecha_ejecucion))</td>
```

Comment: Genial, justo lo que necesitaba, saludos

Answer (score 0):

La funcion **ToShortDateString** se encarga de ello

```
string asd = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Imagino que tu modelo devuelve un DateTime.

```
Model[i].Fecha_solicitud.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero esto: Model[i].Fecha_solicitud.ToShortDateString() marca error

Comment: En todo caso en tu c# realiza el formato a tu DateTime y luego retorna el string.

Comment: Como seria eso " realiza el formato a tu DateTime y luego retorna el string" disculpa?

Comment: Tu modelo tiene una variable DateTime en Fecha_solicitud (tiene que ser DateTime), aplicando el metodo extensivo ToShortDateString(), te devolverá un string con un formato corto solo en fecha.

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar toString con el formato requerido ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

ejemplo:

```
Model[i].Fecha_solicitud.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Model[i].Fecha_ejecucion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero ToString marca error

Comment: Si ToString marca error es probable que el valor de Model[i].Fecha_ejecucion sea nulo. ¿Que tipo de dato contiene?

Comment: Model[i].Fecha_ejecucion contiene un datetime

Answer (score 0):

prueba cambiando lo siguiente.

```
 @Convert.ToDateTime(@Model[i].Codigo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```